# Getting my asp.net webpage to find a connected camera, then stream to a Bitmap constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap, webcam

I need my asp.net web form (C# code-behind) to find a connected camera (phone or computer), then stream the data to a Bitmap constructor.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(Stream streamFromCam);

// Will then process this stream looking for a QR Code using the .NET Barcode
// scanner .dll I've integrated into my project. This part I can do.
```

Is this achievable?
If so, how?

Comment: Do you mean a camera connected to the Web Server?

Comment: If this is possible, you'd have to do this from the browser in javascript. The code behind is irrelevant unless it is your server that has the camera that you want to stream from.

Comment: For capturing video from the client this seem to work for many, https://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/

Answer (score 1):

If the camera is connected to the web server that is running your web application, then yes, it is doable from the code-behind. If you're asking if it is achievable on a remote client with a camera connected, then the answer is yes and no. Yes, you can still do it, no you can't do it from code behind. You would need some Silverlight/flash component to accomplish this... Or ActiveX... or Browser Plug-in, but you can't do it from code-behind. Code behind runs on the server, not the client and devices connected to the client are not accessible via the server side code.

Comment: Yes, I am asking to achieve this remotely on the client side and see where you're coming from.

Comment: @Ivan, As suggested by TimWagaman, you need to use a third-party component to achieve this. You can check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529721/Take-a-Photo-from-a-Desktop-Webcam-and-Upload-in-a) from codeproject. Besides the formats mentioned in the article, bitmap is also supported.

Answer (score 0):

Well, short answer no.  Long answer, yes, sort of, but you're not going to like how.

First, I'm going on the assumption that you want to find a camera on the user's computer, not on the server hosting your page.  That kind of thing is not accessible in the browser without installing additional software.  You would have to get the user to download a program that reads data from their webcam and uploads it to a Web Service.

Doing that is a whole project in itself, and won't fit into a Stack Overflow response.

Comment: Errrm... You're both right, I need to detect the cam client side.

Comment: If I had a WinForm project on the client computer, would it be possible then?

Comment: Yup, that would make it possible.